# Kile project setup bug

Tags: ubuntu, kile

I tried to make a project setup in Kile, making the XeLaTeX command output directory `../output` as an experiment. It 1) didn't work and 2) can't be changed back.

Now whenever I try to run the command, it says `[XeLaTeX] Could not change to the folder path-to-parent-directory/output.`, and if I try to change the settings back, it simply ignores the change for the next time I open settings. I now have to run xelatex from the Kile commandline, which gets annoying in the long run.

Has anyone managed to get this kind of setup to work, and how?

And how do I get changes to stick?

All in all, the Kile settings wizard seems a bit unstable, with the 'apply'-button only appearing on correct manipulation of window size and whatnot.

Comment: I haven't found it especially unstable but things like the output directory settings don't work properly. (This is supposed to be fixed in the next version - whenever that becomes available.) I would try making a new variant of the build setting and then deleting the original, or make a new build setting altogether and then delete the old one.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very simple way to restore the original behaviour of the compiler.
If you change the output directory once you can't erase it anymore. This much is certain. 
But you can change the output dir to ./ (which means present directory).